# passing the result of a query into a variable from node.js to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sql-server, ejs

i'm trying to get some data from MSSQL using Node.js and then pass the data from node to my HTML layout (EJS), but i'm facing some a problem in the last part, this is what i'm trying to do:

app.js file:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var data = getJson(); // Function that return my data
    res.render(__dirname + '/index.ejs', {
        data: data
    }, (err, file) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.send(file);
    });
});
```

Function (also in the same file):

```
function getJson(config) {
    sql.connect(config, err => {
        if (err) return err;
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from data', (err, json) => {
            if (err) return err;
            var result = JSON.stringify(json); // I tried to stringfy this, but doesn't work neither
            console.log(result); // This console inside of the function works!
            return result;
        });
    });
    return result;
};
```

Then when I load the page I get the result "undefined".

But if I pass just a simple variable through the app.get, it works!:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var data = 'data'; // Simple variable
    res.render(__dirname + '/index.ejs', {
        data: data // It works!!!
    }, (err, file) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.send(file);
    });
});
```

Then I tried to make a simple function and see if the result can be showed, an it does!:

```
function getJson() {
    var data = 'data'; // It works too!!!
    return data;
};
```

So I don't know what i'm doing wrong anymore, can any of you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending your data before await for them...

You should learn what is async function...

Look at this next code :

```
function getJson(config) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql.connect(config, err => {
        if (err) return resolve(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from data', (err, json) => {
            if (err) return reject(error);
            var result = JSON.stringify(json); // I tried to stringfy this, but doesn't work neither
            console.log(result); // This console inside of the function works!
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
    })
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    getJson()
    .then(data => {
       res.render(__dirname + '/index.ejs', {
            data: data
        }, (err, file) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.send(file);
         });
    })
    .catch(error => { /* do something  */  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getJson` is doing an async operation. That is why you pass a callback to `sql.connect` and another to `request.query`.

It is like this. When you call `getJson`, the `sql.connect` function is executed, and the rest of the function continues running (`return result;`). That is why you get undefined.